# How to make audio input device from java application

Tags: java, windows, audio, javasound

I'm thinking about making an application that makes audio in a Java application.

The main purpose is that I can use this music as if it was on my microphone.
Example: "I make the music and I let it be heard by my friends on Skype".
How can I set the audio of my app to a windows input device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it in pure Java. Good starting place for information on the subject can be found here in the: [`AudioSystem` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html).